# How to write text in border of container as header/title in flutter

Tags: flutter

How shall I write a "partnership" (as shown in below image) on the border of the container

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1plu.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do using `CustomPainter` or Custom `ShapeBorder`, this is an example using ShapeBorder:

```
        class CustomBorderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Material(
              color: Colors.black,
              shape: _HexagonBorder(),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 30.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Partnership",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }

        class _HexagonBorder extends ShapeBorder {
          const _HexagonBorder();

          @override
          EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions {
            return const EdgeInsets.only();
          }

          @override
          Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
            return getOuterPath(rect, textDirection: textDirection);
          }

          @override
          Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
            return Path()
              ..moveTo(rect.left + rect.width / 6.0, rect.top)
              ..lineTo(rect.right - rect.width / 6.0, rect.top)
              ..lineTo(rect.right, rect.top + rect.height / 2.0)
              ..lineTo(rect.right - rect.width / 6.0, rect.bottom)
              ..lineTo(rect.left + rect.width / 6.0, rect.bottom)
              ..lineTo(rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.height / 2.0)
              ..close();
          }

          @override
          void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {}

          // This border doesn't support scaling.
          @override
          ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
            return null;
          }
        }
```